# no water coming out of the hot water faucet in my tub

Tags: plumbing

Space heater has been pointed at the tub for 12 hours and heat has been above 74 degrees but still no hot water just a trickle from the faucet.

Comment: I take it you are suspecting a frozen pipe?  You need to get heat on the part of the pipe that's frozen.  Heating the tub area is probably not effective.

Comment: Plumber said the pipe that feeds the faucet is located there and I should point the heater at the wall. No?

Comment: No hot water only? How about cold? Close off areas that are allowing cold air to enter the crawlspace as well. Is this a house or mobile home?

Comment: Thanks, Crawl space is in the other room in a closed closet and temp in house is 75. Where should the space heater be set up younthink?

Comment: Cold water trickling ...it is a townhouse Jerry

Comment: You have hot water from some other faucet?

Answer (score 0):

Start under the house with the space heater. The house temp inside is fine. Turn on all the cold water sources all the way. The more water you can get flowing the better. The cold water feeds the hot water heater. Go to the street and place some insulation inside the meter box (towels, rags,etc.) If you have any exposed piping outside... wrap it. If it's a townhome you may be sharing water with a neighbor and its on their side. If your water is off and the meter is spinning it may not be on your side.

Comment: So heat the basement pipes with a hair dryer perhaps.? And turn all the cold water faucets on in all rooms while doing so? Beyond that I have to rely on a plumber for outside work.

Comment: Edits added to post

Comment: Jerry and Mike thank you for your time,knowledge and advice. Very kind of you to take the time to share regardless of how this turns out. Sincerely appreciate it.